# How can I get the latest block from BitShares using pybitshares?

Tags: blockchain

How do I get the latest BitShares block using [`pybitshares`](http://docs.pybitshares.com/en/latest/index.html) in Python?

I can get a given block ID using the following code.

```py
from bitshares import BitShares as BitSharesNode

bitshares = BitSharesNode(
    'wss://api-us-testnet.61bts.com/ws`,
    nobroadcast=False,
    keys=['key-goes-here'],
)
b = Block(
    1,
    blockchain_instance=self.bitshares,
)
print(b)
```

Which yields:

```
<Block 1>
```

But, after reading the section in the docs regarding the [`Block` object](http://docs.pybitshares.com/en/latest/bitshares.block.html), and also searching the source code, I cannot find a way to get the latest block as I can do with `web3`.

Does anyone know how to get the latest block from BitShares using the `pybitshares` package?

Answer (score 1):

Someone in a Telegram channel gave me a clue, which led to the following solution.  Figured I'd post it while it's still fresh in my head.

```py
from bitshares.block import Block
from bitshares.blockchain import Blockchain

bitshares = BitSharesNode(
    "wss://api-us-testnet.61bts.com/ws",
    nobroadcast=False,
    keys=["key-goes-here"],
)
bc = Blockchain(
    blockchain_instance=bitshares,
)
b = bc.get_current_block_num()
print(f'Latest BitShares block number is: {b}')
```

Which yields:

```
Latest BitShares block number is: 56610934
```